# Developing accessory for iOS devices without MFi Program

Tags: ios

**I am developing a device that will communicate with an app installed on an iOS device. I have some doubts:**

- If I use an [MFi](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) cable, do I need to license my product?
- To communicate by serial port, is it necessary to license the product?
- Is there any way to communicate with the USB cable that does not require the license?
- I have nowhere found the cost to license the product, for both development and manufacturing.

The device will be connected and powered over USB.

**Note**: A proprietary iOS application will be developed to communicate with the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You'll need to obtain an MFi Program license. The cost, viability and special API access (if any) can be determined only after contacting Apple.

To get more details, and to get in touch with an Apple correspondent, check out [MFi Program homepage](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/).

Answer (score 1):

It appears the the resultant (software) product will be your own. It is up to *you* what, if *any* license be applied. If you choose to use *source* from another vendor. You need only apply *their* restrictions, if any. To *their* source (if included).

If there is no license available (listed) with their source. Its restrictions (if any) are *unknown*. So you should be unencumbered.